# Powershell command to run Sharepoint 2013 COnfig wizard as another User with credentials

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell

I need to run the SharePoint Configuration wizard with other user credentials. Need to run this through powershell.

Need help on this.

Thanks

Comment: Right click on PS and select run as another user?

Answer (score 1):

Run "SharePoint 2013 Management Shell" as a different user:
[image]
[image]

Then run the SharePoint configuration command.